# VSCode gives "Install Python" error even if it is installed

Tags: python

I get the Python is not installed even if i did install it. I tried deleting and installing python and the extension but it didn't fixed the problem.

Comment: Make sure you have added python to your system path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. install python from the website:  https://www.python.org/
   (make sure you check the box `add to path`).
2. then add the `vscode` extension:  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python
   (you can do this from within `vscode`).

Here is a `hello world` tutorial:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python